Unable to select saved password and username on chrome: fix
I was having an issue trying to log into websites where I have the username and password saved in Chrome. The pop up would appear showing my username and hidden password but I couldn't select it. It was like the touch screen just stopped working. I found a thread here with other people with a similar problem but was unable to comment because I didn't have enough points.
Anyway...I fixed it. My phone needed a security update.
Go to settings, security, updates and search for new updates. Download and install and the problem should be fixed.
Hope this helps someone.
